# php script runs from the browser but not from cron job

Tags: linux, php, cron

I am using *Centos 7* as my webserver. When I run `script.php` from the browser, it works fine and processes all the data in the MySQL table.

When I run it using a cron job, it runs forever but will not process any data.

Can someone explain why this happens what should I do to be able to run the script as a cron job

Comment: Could be any number of things - what user was the cron job running at ?  What is the source of the data ?

Comment: Put traces in your PHP script to see what is actually happening, and write them somewhere you can check later.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php command to call the script you can try to call the script (url) using wget comand it should be more similar to calling it trough browser. Some aditional info could be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766772/using-wget-to-run-a-cronjob-php

The differences explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930936/wget-curl-and-php-for-cronjobs

Comment: Thank you user301441 for the links. I Found them very useful.